# Passing string to dll mehods from Windows application using C++

Tags: c++, winforms, dll

We are currently working to create simple Windows application which will load dll file and call different methods in dll.

**Below is the status:**

1. Windows application design --> OK
2. Load .dll on button click from UI --> OK
3. Call methods in .dll file on button click from UI --> ok
4. Pass string to .dll methods on button click --> NOK

**Method in .dll**

```
    sendReqXml(char *xmlString) 
    {   
    printf("\nsendReqXml() +\n");

    //we will write xmlstring in file here to check what we received  from  UI console

    FILE *out;

    if ((out = fopen("C:\\Users\\20105388\\Desktop\\textfile.txt", "w")) != NULL)
     {
       fprintf(out, "the range is '%s'\n", xmlString);
       fclose(out);
     }

      //.... then proceed further 
    }
```

**UI console method**

```
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::-Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
  char *xmlFile = "I am sending text from UI";
  DLLSEND _SENDXML;
  _SENDXML = (DLLSEND) GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "sendReqXml");

 if (_SENDXML != NULL)
   {
     _SENDXML(xmlFile);
   }
}
```

We are just trying to print a string in file in sendReqXml method to check what we received from UI.

```
  fprint(out,"the range is '%s'\n", xmlString);
```

whatever string we pass from UI, above method writes below output in file

```
  **the range is '„¹&Z'**
```

Which is not correct, so can anyone help to fix the issue?

**Note:**

While working with command line the above method works perfectly fine and write correct output in file.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sounds like a UNICODE issue. 16bit chars vs 8 bit. UnicodeToCodePage(1252,xmlString);

Comment: Could also be a file write encoding option.

Comment: @James Thanks for the update. our main intention is not to write on file but pass the string from UI to server via dll, but as we wanted to check what string we received from UI so we are writing on file. but anyways I will try with above help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to call a native c/c++ dll function on managed c++(c++/cli).
Right?
So... Have you tried PInvoke ?
Reference this page
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235282.aspx